# Not returning any row from table

Tags: hibernate

I am fetching data from database there are 6 rows in table but it is not showing any output in program. What may be the problem my code is below.
It is not showin any error in console.

```
public class smsDAO {

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
public List<SmsGateway> fetchAll() {
        System.out.println("Calling fetchA b");
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<SmsGateway> sms = null;
        try {
            sms = session.createQuery("FROM sms_gateway").list();
            tx.commit();
            for (SmsGateway s : sms) {
                System.out.println(s.getDescription() + " " + s.getUrl1());
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Calling fetchA re  ");
        return sms;
    }
}
```

Comment: "sms_gateway" is this name of java class or DB table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is not shwing any error because you deliberatey chose to ignore the exceptions thrown. Replace

```
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
```

by

```
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }
```

And re-read the chapter about HQL in the documentation. HQL always uses names of entities and their mapped field. It never uses table names. So the query should be

```
select s from SmsGateway s
```

Also, respect the Java naming conventions: Classes start with an uppercase letter.